# Null Values and Global Functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to write a reusable JavaScript library. In an attempt to do this, I'm writing some formatting tools. For example, I currently have the following:

```
Object.prototype.ToPercentage = function() {
  return this + '%';
};
```

I was excited about this approach because I could use it similar to an extension method in C#. However, I learned via my unit tests that this approach will not work with null values. In other words:

```
// This works
var v1 = 100;
var result1 = v1.ToPercentage();

// This causes an error
var v2 = null;
var result2 = v2.ToPercentage();  // Causes an exception because v2 is null
```

Is there a way around this challenge with `null` values? If not, how can I define a `ToPercentage` as part of my reusable library without worrying that it will conflict with other named functions?

Thanks!

Comment: What would you expect out of a null or undefined value if it did work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you are not able to do this in javascript. I would prefer to write a global function and use it like this:

```
var v1 = 100;
var result1 = percentage(v1);

var v2 = null;
var result2 = percentage(v2);
```

If you have defined a 'namespace' for your library. You can add the `percentage` function to your 'namespace'. Like this:

```
// 'mylib' is your namespace
window.mylib = {};

window.mylib.percentage = function (value) {
    // ...
};

var result = mylib.percentage(null);
```

The namespace `mylib` can be changed to some shorter word (so it looks more elegant). For example, use `$` instead of `mylib', then you can use it like this:

```
var result = $.percentage(null);
```

**NOTICE**: Many existing libraries like jQuery already use `$`, so you should make sure they won't conflict. I would prefer to use short alias (2 or 3 chars) of your project name as the 'namesapce'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global object with a unique name and place your functions in it:

```
window.MyLibrary = {
  ToPercentage: function(x) {
    return (typeof x === 'number') ? (x + '%') : 'error';
  },

  // other functions here
};

var v1 = 100;
var result1 = MyLibrary.ToPercentage(v1);

var v2 = null;
var result2 = MyLibrary.ToPercentage(v2);
```

Or if you really want it to be part of Object, add it to Object itself rather than its prototype:

```
Object.ToPercentage = function(x) {
  return (typeof x === 'number') ? (x + '%') : 'error';
};

var v1 = 100;
var result1 = Object.ToPercentage(v1);

var v2 = null;
var result2 = Object.ToPercentage(v2);
```

Essentially, this makes it a class method rather than an instance method.  This has the added benefit that the property name "ToPercentage" will not appear in the enumerated list of properties of every object.